# new DOMDocument обрезает данные в json в PHP

Tags: php, json, парсер

Вот допустим есть сайт откуда я беру данные, которые находятся в json(по ссылке).
Когда я пишу

```
$html = file_get_contents("тут.ссылка");
```

И вывожу это то он выводит все записи которые есть в этом json. Представим что  всего записей 20к. В цикле я хочу пройтись по этому файлу и забрать данные по конкретным значениям(к примеру items {name: "laala"}.
Я подключаю домБиблиотеку:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$dom->loadHTML($html);
```

И вот почему-то после этого когда я вывожу эти данные чтобы посмотреть, то вижу что вместо 20к записей там уже 16к. И когда я начинаю декодировать эти данные то постоянно получаю NULL, но  стоит мне сократить декод до 16к значений, то всё ок, но мне то нужно все 20к. С чем проблема может быть связана?

Comment: Зачем подключать DOMDocument, если данные в джсоне?

Comment: потому что данные json находятся не у меня, а на сайте и я их просто дёргаю оттуда

Comment: @u_mulder скорее всего имел ввиду, что полученный JSON можно десериализовать и работать далее с ним как с объектом.

Comment: Для этого не нужен DOMDocument.